# Unable to send dynamic invoice value to struts2 server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, struts2

I am working on angularjs 1.6.5

I am using following code to send data of invoice page.

```js
$scope.products = [{qty: 0, description: ' ', sellingPrice: 0.0, unitPrice: 0.0, total: 0.0}];
$scope.fproducts = [];
$scope.generateInvoice = function () {
    console.log("generateInvoice");
    console.log($scope.fproducts);
    console.log("sub total " + $scope.subTotal + " ft " + $scope.finalTotal + "  pamt " + $scope.paidAmount + "  baldue " + $scope.balancedue);
    $scope.bd1 = {
        'subTotal': $scope.subTotal,
        'total': $scope.finalTotal,
        'TotalPaid': $scope.paidAmount,
        'invDateStr': $filter('date')($scope.invoiceDate, "MM/dd/yyyy"),

    };
    if ($scope.fproducts.length > 0) {
        $scope.fproducts.forEach((total, index) => {
            Object.entries(total).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                console.log(index + "  " + key + " " + value);
                $scope.bd1[`billProductList[${index}].${key}`] = value;
            });
        });
    }
    //commenting above for each and removing comment from below code is 
    // working properly but I want to send dynamic data with above code
/*  $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].id`] = 1;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].description`] = 1;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].discountPercent`] = 150;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].qty`] = 10;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].sellingPrice`] = 100;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].unitPrice`] = 100;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].total`] = 150;*/

    $scope.bd1[`BillPaidDetailses[0].paymentMode`] = $scope.paymentMode;
    $scope.bd1[`BillPaidDetailses[0].amount`] = $scope.paidAmount; 
    console.log($scope.bd1);
```

```js
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'added-invoice',
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.bd1),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.data.st === 1) {
            $scope.success = true;
            window.location = 'bhome#!/show-tax';

        } else if (data.data.st === 0) {
            $scope.success = false;
            $scope.failure = true;
        } else if (data.data.st === -1) {
            $scope.success = false;
            $scope.failure = true;
        }
    }, function errorCallback(data, status, header, config) {
        $scope.success = false;
        $scope.failure = true;
    });
}
```

Above code is not passing value to server side object.
its console.log value is[image]

on modifying above data

```
   /*if ($scope.fproducts.length > 0) {
        $scope.fproducts.forEach((total, index) => {
            Object.entries(total).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                console.log(index + "  " + key + " " + value);
                $scope.bd1[`billProductList[${index}].${key}`] = value;
            });
        });
    }*/
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].id`] = 1;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].description`] = 1;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].discountPercent`] = 150;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].qty`] = 10;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].sellingPrice`] = 100;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].unitPrice`] = 100;
    $scope.bd1[`billProductList[0].total`] = 150;
```

as this is passing value to server object
its console.log is [image]

I want to run my code using dynamic value specified in if condition.
What is the problem I am unable to get it.

**EDIT**  I am using server side struts2
my code is

```
public class BillNewAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<BillDetails> {

    BillDetails bd = new BillDetails();
    private List<BillDetails> billList = new ArrayList<BillDetails>();

    public String insert() {
        System.out.println("total " + bd.getTotal()
                + " subTotal " + bd.getSubTotal() + " paid " 
                + bd.getTotalPaid()
                + " invoiceDate " + bd.getInvDateStr()
        );
        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        try {
            bd.setInvoiceDate((new java.sql.Date(formatter1.parse(bd.getInvDateStr()).getTime())));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BillNewAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        for (BillPaidDetails b : bd.getBillPaidDetailses()) {
            System.out.println("type " + b.getPaymentMode() + " amount "
                + b.getAmount()
            );
        }
        System.out.println("product size " + bd.getBillPrList().size());
        for (BillProduct b : bd.getBillPrList()) {
            System.out.println("id " + b.getId() + " desc  " 
                + b.getDescription() + " qty " + b.getQty()
                + " sp " + b.getSellingPrice() + " up " 
                + b.getUnitPrice() + " " + b.getTotal()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

public class BillDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private Long billNo;
private Client client;
private BigDecimal subTotal;
private BigDecimal TotalAmount;//total price
private BigDecimal TotalPaid;//Amount paid for  getting items
private BigDecimal vat;
private BigDecimal total;
private String invoiceNo;
private Date invoiceDate;
private String invDateStr;
private List<BillPaidDetails> BillPaidDetailses = new ArrayList<BillPaidDetails>();
private List<BillProduct> billPrList = new ArrayList<BillProduct>();
//getter and setter
 }
```

---

I have to send data in `$scope.bd1[billProductList[0].id] = 1;` format to server

Assigning indivisual value passing the data to server but I have dynamic no of values so I am trying

```
if ($scope.fproducts.length > 0) { 
    $scope.fproducts.forEach((total, index) => {
        Object.entries(total).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(index + " " + key + " " + value);
            $scope.bd1[billProductList[${index}].${key}] = value;
        });
    });
}
```

that is not working

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Struts JSON Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/)

The JSON plugin provides a json result type that serializes actions into JSON.

1. The `content-type` must be `application/json`
2. Action must have a public “setter” method for fields that must be populated.
3. Supported types for population are: `Primitives (int,long…String)`, `Date`, `List`, `Map`, `Primitive Arrays`, other class, and `Array` of `Other` class.
4. Any object in JSON, that is to be populated inside a list, or a map, will be of type `Map` (mapping from properties to values), any whole number will be of type `Long`, any decimal number will be of type `Double`, and any array of type `List`.

**Your actions can accept incoming JSON** if they are in package which uses json interceptor or by adding reference to it.

This simplifies the AngularJS HTTP POST request:

```
$scope.bd1 = {
    'subTotal': $scope.subTotal,
    'total': $scope.finalTotal,
    'TotalPaid': $scope.paidAmount,
    'invDateStr': $scope.invoiceDate.toISOString(),
    'billProductList': $scope.fproducts,  
};

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'added-invoice',
    data: $scope.bd1,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    if (data.st === 1) {
        $scope.success = true;
        window.location = 'bhome#!/show-tax';
    } else if (data.st === 0) {
        $scope.success = false;
        $scope.failure = true;
    } else if (data.data.st === -1) {
        $scope.success = false;
        $scope.failure = true;
    }
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.failure = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be because `console.log(index + "  " + key + " " + value)` is returning correct value as you are getting inside loop.

try to access the below piece of code, after assigning to `$scope.bd1`:

```
Object.entries(total).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  $scope.bd1[`billProductList[${index}].${key}`] = value;
  console.log($scope.bd1[`billProductList[${index}].${key}`]);
});
```

And I guess `$scope.bd1` is not getting updated hence it is not passing value to server side object.

Answer (score 0):

$scope.bd1[`billProductList[${index}].${key}`] = value; you are overriding  value  on this line of code

> $scope.bd1[`billProductList[${index}${index2}].${key}`] you can change shape of object as per you need

```
$scope.fproducts.forEach((total, index) => {
    Object.entries(total).forEach(([key, value],index2) => {
        console.log(index + "  " + key + " " + value);
        $scope.bd1[`billProductList[${index}${index2}].${key}`] = value;
    });
})
```

Comment: billProductList[${index}${index2}].${key} is generating code as billProductList[01].description

Comment: yes i know it would produce object in this "billProductList[01] format" because you have two loop so to prevent overlap we have to generate unique key that why i am using index of both loop, can you please tell me after making this change  are you able to pass value to backed?

Comment: No not getting value